# Lost requests body in Swift/Vapor http server

Tags: swift, apache, vapor

I have a pretty standard Vapor http server, It has a middleware where it inspects the request body and does some authentication validation.

```
func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
     var myStuff: SomeCommonPattern? =  try request.content.decode(SomeCommonPattern?.self)
```

SomeCommonPattern is a base class for all other requests in the group.
That works very well in debug on Mac. When I run this in docker on my Mac laptop it still works as expected. I put it through a rigorous tests with a hundred clients making simultaneous requests for hours. Not a single failure. Now I moved the same docker image to a production machine, which is Ubuntu with lover specs than my machine, and my code still works with exception when it does not.
About 1 request out of 5 fails to decode the request. I put some additional logging and   sure enough, **sometimes** request.body.string is empty when most other same requests are fine. Anyone knows what could be happening ? It looks almost like the body of the request is still in transit when the middleware is being called. It happens even when I make requests from a single client.

Edit: I just realized that on my laptop the service is running directly, while on the linux machine it is behind apache 2 reverse proxy. It is probably a significant detail but I still do not know the reason of the intermittent behavior.

Edit 2:
I moved the failing code out of the middleware and put in every endpoint implementation. It is much less convenient and more error prone but now my application works 100% of the time. That may confirm that apache is off the hook and the problem is indeed in Vapor, or my misunderstanding how to use it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a GET request?

Comment: I do have get request with a body ( which I probably should not have) but my post requests also are failing from time to time.

Comment: Not sure why the question was closed and who does it. Anyway to help others who runs into the same issue here is the answer I received in Vapor github:  "request.body can be nil if the bodyStorage is still stream. You can call collect method in your Middleware."

Comment: It was closed because there was no way for us to reproduce or analyze the problem.

Comment: had the same issue, body sometimes nil in a middleware. expanding on the hint above, you can do something like `let buffer = try await req.body.collect().get()` and then turn it into a String: `let body = String(data: Data(buffer: buffer), encoding: .utf8)`